# MPI Программа на си

Tags: linux, c, mpi

Когда запускаю программу с помощью команды mpirun, prinf срабатывает столько же раз, сколько я задал процессов и получается вот такой нелицеприятны вывод. Как сделать что бы при запуски MPI программы printf срабатывал только один раз?  [image: скриншот экрана]

Comment: Печатайте в консоль и читайте из консоли только в процессе с индексом 0.

Comment: Спаси большое, выручили.